# One excessive icon (Safely Remove Hardware and Eject Media ) after changing the BIOS to AHCI

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, bios, sata, ahci

I installed the x64 version of Win 7. After that I modified the "*regedit*" and then changed the SATA selection mode to AHCI (which was in IDE mode before) in BIOS.

But;

1- One excessive icon has been appeared in bottom right-hand corner. When I click on it, a small window appears that says:

*Open devices and printers
Eject ST500DM002-1BC142 ATA Device (this is my HDD!)
- ...(C)
-....(D)
-....(E)*

I think it belongs to the HDD. How to get rid of it?

2- Should the settings of the BIOS (SATA selection mode) always be in AHCI and don't I need to return it to IDE even if I want to re-install the (x64 or x86) OS?

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of the icon, go in to your bios and select the hard drive and simply disable hot swap/hot-plug on that port. That icon means it is a hot plug enabled port for swapping of hard drives.

I would always use AHCI if your operating system supports it as it adds features such as NCQ which improve system performance significantly.

Comment: Thank you William Hilsum, it seems to be easier! But just one more question, "_disabling hot swap/hot-plug_" does't have any _bad effect_ (or something like that), on the system?

Comment: No, infact I would say it is bad to have on internal ports.... Internal ports are used for internal drives, which need permanent power and it is a bad idea to add/remove power to a machine whilst it is on as you risk burning out the PSU. You only want to enable this option for built in ESATA ports, or if you are using a port to an ESATA backplate such as http://www.shop.bt.com/images/product/uni2/5c/5ccl_xlarge.jpg where you would use external power.

Comment: I disabled the "Hot Plug" of the HDD from BIOS but still that icon exists!!

Comment: Intel rapid storage technology solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is normal. AHCI supports hot-plug (and as such also hot-remove). Vendor-specific AHCI drivers (from Intel or AMD or whatever) *might* suppress this.
2. Always use AHCI. Windows 7 supports this out of the box, so do Linux and FreeBSD.